# Distribution function method for density functions

Tags: statistics

Okay so I have been trying to solve a problem in statistics for a while, but I end up getting the wrong answer all the time..

the problem is

$f(y) = 2(1-y), \ 0 \leq y \leq 1$ and $0$ elsewhere

I have to find the density function for $U_{1} = 2Y-1$

Firstly I get that $F_{U}(u) = P(U \leq u) = P ( -\frac{u+1}{2} \leq Y \leq \frac{u+1}{2}) $

to find $f_{y}dy$ I integrate so we have that

$\int_{-\frac{u+1}{2}}^{\frac{u+1}{2}}fydy = F_{Y}(\frac{u+1}{2}) - F_{y} (- \frac{u+1}{2})$

So we have that

$f_{U}(u) = \frac{1}{2} ( f_{Y} ( \frac{u+1}{2})+f_{Y}(-\frac{u+1}{2})$

since $f(y) = 2(1-y)$

$f_{U}(u) = \frac{1}{2} ( 2 ( - \frac{u+1}{2} + 2) + ( 1 + \frac{u+1}{2})) = 2$

But according to my textbook 2 is not the right answer, and I cant really see where my mistake is, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $F_{U}(u) = P(U \leq u) = P ( -\frac{u+1}{2} \leq Y \leq \frac{u+1}{2}) $

should be

$F_{U}(u) = P(U \leq u) = P ( Y \leq \frac{u+1}{2})=F_Y\left(\frac{u+1}2 \right) $

$$f_U(u) = \frac12f_Y\left( \frac{u+1}2\right)$$

Comment: thank you do you mind telling why?

Comment: $P(U \le u) = P(2Y-1 \le u)$, I just solve the inequality.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I guess I got confused because I was comparing it to an example with squares included